# Find array in multidimensional array and insert it into another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array output shaped like a tree like this, let's just call it `$tree`:

```
      Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => null
            [count] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [Dagadu Bocah] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Dagadu Bocah
                            [count] => 47
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [HirukPikuk] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => HirukPikuk
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [DGD] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => DGD
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DGD] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => DGD
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                            [count] => 2
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [Dagadu] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Dagadu
                            [count] => 341
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [HirukPikuk] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => HirukPikuk
                                            [count] => 35
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                            [count] => 2
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [DGD] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => DGD
                                                            [count] => 7
                                                            [child] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                                            [count] => 3
                                                                            [child] => 
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )
```

I also have an array with an array of keys like this, just call it `$item`:

```
    array (size=5)
  'Dagadu' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'Dagadu Bocah' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'HirukPikuk' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'DGD' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'Malioboroman' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

I think to do the following:

1. take each nested array in the `$tree` with the reference `$item` as the end of the nested array then insert it as array value of `$item` for example like this:

   ```
    Array
   (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [item] => null
               [count] => 0
               [child] => Array
                   (
                       [Dagadu Bocah] => Array //take this
                           (
                               [item] => Dagadu Bocah
                               [count] => 47
                               [child] => Array
                                   (
                                    [HirukPikuk] => Array // and take this
                                           (
                                               [item] => HirukPikuk
                                               [count] => 5
                                               [child] => Array
                                                   (
                                                [DGD] => Array //last nested array as refenrence
                                                           (
                                                               [item] => DGD
                                                               [count] => 1
                                                               [child] => 
                                                           )
   ```
2. if there are 2 or more nested array nodes I will implode with the separator is ',':

   $a = {{dagadu bocah, hiruk pikuk}}
3. Then insert the value into the `$item` array according to the key by adding a new array called 'count' to indicate how many times the nested array ending in the key of $item is found in the `$tree` array:

   'DGD' => 
       array (size=1)
         dagadu bocah, hiruk pikuk =>
            [count] = 1
4. if a loop occurs like number 3, the count will increase. thought it would be like this:

   'DGD' => 
   array (size=1)
     dagadu bocah, hiruk pikuk =>
        [count] = 2

my question is:

I have made a foreach loop from the `$item` array and then I was confused about what to use to find the `$ite`m key array at each end of the nested array in the `$tree`. What I've tried is to use `in_array` and then combine it with an null array count *because every end of the nested array in this has a null* but it turns out that `in_array` can't do it. so, what must i use inside this function?

```
        public function buildFPTree2($item, $tree)
    {
      $conditionalPattern=array();
      foreach($item as $key => $value){
        $conditionalPattern[$key]=[];
      }
//some function here
      if(in_array('DGD', $tree)){

      }else{

      }

    }
```